# Can not read enough data from a file when the file has enough data c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have this code in c++ ( it is after I did some tests to see why I can not read enough data from file, so it is not final code and I am looking to find why I am getting this result)

```
size_t readSize=629312;
_rawImageFile.seekg(0,ifstream::end);
size_t s=_rawImageFile.tellg();
char *buffer=(char*) malloc(readSize);
_rawImageFile.seekg(0);
int p=_rawImageFile.tellg();
_rawImageFile.read(buffer,readSize);
size_t extracted = _rawImageFile.gcount();
cout << "s="<< s <<endl;
cout << "p="<< p <<endl;
cout << "readsize="<< readSize<<endl;
cout << "extracted="<< extracted <<endl;
cout << "eof ="<< _rawImageFile.eofbit<<endl;
cout << "fail="<< _rawImageFile.failbit <<endl;
```

The output is as follow:

```
s=3493940224
p=0
readsize=629312
extracted=2085
eof =1
fail=2
```

As you can see the file size is 3493940224 and I am at the start of file (p=0) and I am trying to read 629312 bytes, but I can only read 2085?

What is the problem with this code? I did open this file in other methods and read some data out of it, but  am using seekg to move pointer to the beginning of file.

The file was opened as binary.

**edit 1**

To find a solution, I put all code inside a function and here is it:

```
    _config=config;
    ifstream t_rawImageFile;
    t_rawImageFile.open(rawImageFileName,std::ifstream::in || std::ios::binary );
    t_rawImageFile.seekg (0);
    size_t readSize=629312;
    t_rawImageFile.seekg(0,ifstream::end);
    size_t s=t_rawImageFile.tellg();
    char *buffer=(char*) malloc(readSize);
    t_rawImageFile.seekg(0);
    size_t p=t_rawImageFile.tellg();
    t_rawImageFile.read(buffer,readSize);
    size_t x=t_rawImageFile.tellg();
    size_t extracted = t_rawImageFile.gcount();
    cout << "s="<< s <<endl;
    cout << "p="<< p <<endl;
    cout << "x="<< x <<endl;
    cout << "readsize="<< readSize<<endl;
    cout << "extracted="<< extracted <<endl;
    cout << "eof ="<< t_rawImageFile.eof()<<endl;
cout << "fail="<< t_rawImageFile.fail() <<endl;
```

and the result is:

```
s=3493940224
p=0
x=4294967295
readsize=629312
extracted=2085
eof =1
fail=1
```

Interestingly, after read the file pointer moves to a very big value. is it possible that since the file size is very big, the application fails?

**edit 2**

Tested the same code with another file. the result is as follow:

```
s=2993007872
p=0
x=4294967295
readsize=629312
extracted=1859
eof =1
fail=1
```

What I can read from this test is that:
after read the file pointer moves to a big number which is always the same. The amount that it reads depend on file (!).

**edit 3**

After changing the size_t to fstream::pos_type the result is as follow:

```
s=2993007872
p=0
x=-1
readsize=629312
extracted=1859
eof =1
fail=1
```

Why file position goes to -1 after a read?

Comment: Where and how do you set `readSize`? Also, what is the stream state (fail/eof/etc)?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why do you use `malloc` in a C++ program?

Comment: @not-sehe: Then what is it? Or are you just of the opinion that C++ should never use `malloc`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am new in c++ (went from c to c#). What is the best alternative?

Comment: C++ have an operator `new` that are usually used to allocate memory. In your case you can use it as `char* buffer = new char[readSize];`. Then you free the allocated memory with `delete`, as in `delete [] buffer;`.

Comment: C++ is a multi-paradigm language. It is C++ code. (question remains how good the code is)

Comment: @not-sehe: Since when did C have class member functions and overloaded operators? This is C++, even if it doesn't use the idioms you prefer.

Comment: I can't see any other obvious reason than that something is truncating your file while you have it open, so your `tellg()` shows a location that's where you `seekg`'d to before truncation.

Comment: probably better to use `fstream::pos_type` instead of `size_t`

Comment: Please post a fully compilable example (see http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Those last two lines should read eof() and fail() if you want useful information.

Comment: By the way, the file position was _always_ -1, but since you were storing it in an unsigned type before, it couldn't represent negative numbers. Read up on [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) for more on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t_rawImageFile.open(rawImageFileName, std::ifstream::in || std::ios::binary );
```

...does not open the file in binary mode. Since `||` is the lazy or operator and `std::ifstream::in` is non zero, the whole expression has the value `1`.

```
t_rawImageFile.open(rawImageFileName, std::ifstream::in | std::ios::binary );
```

...will surely work better.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the part where your file is being opened, but I'm pretty sure it is missing `ios::binary` to make sure the C runtime code doesn't interpret CTRL-Z (or CTRL-D) as end of file.

Comment: the file opened in this way: _rawImageFile.open(rawImageFileName,std::ifstream::in || std::ifstream::binary);

Comment: Then something else is wrong. Without access to your file and your environment, it's hard to say what.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
t_rawImageFile.open(rawImageFileName,std::ifstream::in || std::ios::binary );
```

into this:

```
t_rawImageFile.open(rawImageFileName,std::ifstream::in | std::ios::binary );
```